# Objective-C static inline NSString array

Tags: objective-c, inline, init, static-array

Hi :) I am trying to create a static C-Array of NSStrings.

This is what I tried:

```
static NSString** polygonNames = {@"Radical Isotope", @"Point", @"Line", @"Triangle", @"Square", @"Pentagon", @"Hextagon", @"Heptagon", @"Octagon", @"Nonagon", @"Decagon", @"Hendecagon", @"Dodecagon",  @"Tridecagon",  @"Tetradecagon",  @"Pentadecagon",  @"Hexadecagon",  @"Heptadecagon", @"Octadecagon", @"Enneadecagon"};
```

No compiler errors, but I am getting 41 warnings, all of which are one of the three following:

```
"warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type"
"warning: excess elements in scalar initializer"
"warning: (near initialization for 'polygonNames')"
```

Which leads me to believe when I use this class, I am going to be presented with plenty of sigbarts or some other memory access error...

What is the proper way to initialize a static array of NSStrings (preferably inline, and I would like to use C-arrays, not NSArrays)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
static NSString *polygonNames[] = { @"Radical Isotope", @"Point", @"Line", /* etc */ };
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. I got too used to my programming paradigms class, having to convert void* to int** etc, etc...